# Keeping only maximum date rows in a group

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery

The following SQL code keeps only the MAX(*date*) rows with the same *id* and *question* values. I would like to know if there is a simpler/ shorter syntax returning the same result.

```
with 
tbl_src as (select * from `tests2.o1.mc` order by id, date),
tbl_max_date as (
  select
    id,
    question,
    MAX(date) as max_date
  from
    `tests2.o1.mc`
  group by
    id,
    question
)
select 
  tbl_src.*
from
  tbl_src
inner join
  tbl_max_date
on
  tbl_src.id  = tbl_max_date.id
  and tbl_src.question  = tbl_max_date.question
  and tbl_src.date  = tbl_max_date.max_date
```

The original data:

| id | date | question | answers |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2018-03-21 | q1 | "[""n1"",""n3""]" |
| 1 | 2018-12-10 | q1 | "[""n1"",""n2"",""n3""]" |
| 1 | 2018-03-21 | q2 | "[""N1"",""n3""]" |
| 1 | 2018-12-10 | q2 | "[""n1"",""n3""]" |
| 1 | 2018-03-21 | q3 | "[""N1""]" |
| 1 | 2018-12-10 | q3 | "[""n2""]" |
| 2 | 2018-03-29 | q1 | "[""n1"",""n3""]" |
| 2 | 2018-06-01 | q1 | "[""n1"",""n2"",""n3""]" |
| 2 | 2018-06-02 | q1 | "[""n1"",""n3""]" |
| 2 | 2018-06-01 | q2 | "[""n1"",""N2""]" |
| 2 | 2018-06-01 | q3 | "[""n3""]" |
| 3 | 2018-03-14 | q1 | "[""n2"",""n3""]" |
| 3 | 2018-03-26 | q2 | "[""n1""]" |
| 3 | 2018-03-14 | q3 | "[""n3""]" |

The result:

| id | date | question | answers |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2018-12-10 | q1 | "[""n1"",""n2"",""n3""]" |
| 1 | 2018-12-10 | q2 | "[""n1"",""n3""]" |
| 1 | 2018-12-10 | q3 | "[""n2""]" |
| 2 | 2018-06-02 | q1 | "[""n1"",""n3""]" |
| 2 | 2018-06-01 | q2 | "[""n1"",""N2""]" |
| 2 | 2018-06-01 | q3 | "[""n3""]" |
| 3 | 2018-03-14 | q1 | "[""n2"",""n3""]" |
| 3 | 2018-03-26 | q2 | "[""n1""]" |
| 3 | 2018-03-14 | q3 | "[""n3""]" |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/numbering_functions#row_number) to rank your data according to `date` for each combination of `id` and `question`; then simply select the row with a `ROW_NUMBER` of 1:

```
WITH tbl_max_date AS (
  SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, question ORDER BY date DESC) AS rn
  FROM tests2.o1.mc
)
SELECT *
FROM tbl_max_date
WHERE rn = 1
```

If you could have more than one row with the same maximum value per group, you can use [`RANK`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/numbering_functions#rank) in place of `ROW_NUMBER`, as that will give all rows with the same value the same ranking. For example:

```
WITH tbl_max_date AS (
  SELECT *,
         RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY id, question ORDER BY date DESC) aS rn
  FROM tbl_src
)
SELECT *
FROM tbl_max_date
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak for Google BigQuery, but in other databases common table expressions impose an optimization boundary and subqueries can perform better; so consider dropping your `with`.

Is the only purpose of `tbl_src` to do an `order by`? It seems so. It's in somewhat of a backwards place, because `order by` can only be guaranteed to be preserved at the outer level of a query and not after a `join`, and anything else that works is "by accident".

Try the following:

```sql
select *
from (
  select id, question, answers, max(date) as max_date
  from `tests2.o1.mc`
  group by id, question, answers
)
order by id, max_date
```

Comment: Thank you for extremely valuable comments! However the proposed query does not return the last field (*answers*). The reason why I first grouped and then joined was to return more fields than just id, question and max_date. About ordering, you are correct. One question from my side: when would it be appropriate to use `with`? Is it cases when I would use the same query more than once?

Comment: I've edited to include `answers`, which simply needs to be in the `group by`. Regarding `with`: the answer is basically "when you can't subquery", which - yes - includes the case where the subquery needs to be reused.

Comment: Some answers in id-question groups differ, so instead of 9 records I get 13. I guess I should use the previous version + a join.

Comment: Let's discuss in https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117358/table-results-for-google-big-query